# expr giving syntax error

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a simple script in bash :

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 number1 operator number2"
        exit 1
fi

opt=$2

case $opt in
        +) echo "$1 + $3 = `expr $1 + $3`";;
        -) echo "$1 - $3 = `expr $1 - $3`";;
        /) echo "$1 / $3 = `expr $1 / $3`";;
        x|X) echo "$1 * $3 = `expr $1 * $3`";;
esac
```

All the cases work fine except for `x|X` one.Why I can't seem to understand.

The error that I get on running `./script.sh 20 x 3` is:

```
expr: syntax error
20 * 3 =
```

I am new to bash scripting so does anyone has any idea as to what can be the solution for this.

Comment: What error are you getting? For what input exactly?

Comment: For the `x|X` case.I edited the question please have a look again.

Comment: You need to quote/escape the `*` so the shell doesn't expand it as a wildcard. Add `set -x` to the top of the script to see what is happening.

Comment: Also, don't use `expr`. Use [Arithmetic Expansions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arithmetic-Expansion) instead ([spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_04)).

Comment: You need `expr $1 \* $3` -- escape the asterisk as Etan suggests

Comment: Arithmetic Expansion worked flawlessly but why `expr` was not working?

Comment: `expr` is an ordinary command, whose arguments are subject to the standard shell processing. `$((...))` is special syntax defined by POSIX, so the contents of the construct are processed outside the normal rules.

Comment: I didnt knew that inside `expr` too we need to escape the * character i.e. it can expand as a wildcard inside `expr`.

Comment: There is nothing "inside" `expr`; it's a command just like `ls` or `cp`. It gets a sequence of arguments that it treats as an expression. Compare `expr 3 + 5` with `expr "3 + 5"`. In the first, the three arguments can be assembled into an expression; in the second, the single argument cannot.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 number1 operator number2"
        exit 1
fi

opt=$2

case $opt in
        +) echo "$1 + $3 = `expr $1 + $3`";;
        -) echo "$1 - $3 = `expr $1 - $3`";;
        /) echo "$1 / $3 = `expr $1 / $3`";;
        x|X) echo "$1 * $3 = `expr $1 \* $3`";;
esac
```